# Can't get ajax to call webmethod

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

I can't seem to get this ajax call to work.
I have this chunk of javascipt:

```
function exportCSV(e) {
    var data = document.getElementById("mainTable").innerHTML;
    $.ajax({
        url: "Handlers/Handler.ashx/saveToCsv",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
       //data: data,
       success: function (msg) {
       alert("Success");
              alert(msg);
       },
       error: function (msg) {
              alert("failed ");
       }
    });
}
```

and then I have a handler.cs file with this method I am trying to call:

```
[WebMethod]
        public static string void saveToCsv()
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            //yet to implement rest
            return "hello";
        }
```

however I can't seem to figure out why it keeps failing.

Comment: The WebMethod doesn't return anything. Try returning some formatted JSON or loose the dataType attribute in the ajax call

Comment: Failing how? Throwing an exception?

Comment: it's giving me the 404 error. even though the file is right next to the .js file. and I made sure the method name was correct by copying/pasting it in the ajax. I'll post my current code

Comment: do you see fail message ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have added below line in your webservice before your webmethod

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe problem in link:

> Handlers/Handler.ashx/saveToCsv

Try to use full path to check this.